# How to call Rest API Post method in Angular 8. Getting CORS error

Tags: spring, api, rest, angular8

I am trying to call Rest API post method in Angular 8.

```
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' :'*','Access-Control-Allow-Methods' :'POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH','Access-Control-Max-Age' :'3600','Access-Control-Allow-Headers' :'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'username':'dexadmin','password':'dexcenter'}
  
  this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/DEXRESTAPI/queues/getMaxJob',{},{​​'headers':headers}).
  
  subscribe((data:any) => {​​

    console.log('Data', +data);

    console.log('Was my name');
  }​​);
}

Rest API is as below:

@RequestMapping(value = "/getMaxJob", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public Integer getMaxJob() throws JmsException {
      
      try {
         return queueDelegate.getMaxJob();
      }
      catch (Exception cause) {
         logger.error("Error getting MaxJob" + cause.getMessage(), cause);
         throw new JmsException(cause.getLocalizedMessage());
      }
   }
```

I am getting 401 unauthorized error. I am getting on consol below error -
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/DEXRESTAPI/queues/getMaxJob/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have set in SecurityConfig.java file

```
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
    }
```

Comment: add  @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080") on top of the getMaxJob() method

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: You can resolve by using proxy config in angular app

Comment: I think that the origin you have to specify to be allowed in the server is the angular one so you have to put @CrossOrigin(origins = "localhost:4200")

Comment: At Angular server side how to do the same. Do i need to code as below ```getBaseUrl() {  
      return 'http://localhost:4200/'; ```
   }